# Can automatic numbered list formatting be turned off in notes?

Tags: macos, notes.app

I'm running notes Version 4.7 (1111.23) on macOS Catalina (10.15.6) and I have a couple documents I want to disable bullets and number formatting.

In TextEdit, the number formatting isn't as aggressive as in Pages or Notes and I wonder if I'm missing a way to disable that either all together in Notes app or better to disable it on the few notes where I just want to type and not get assistance in numbering.

To be clear - I understand that after I type the following, it corrects my typing and prompts for another dash list entry:

-<kbd>space</kbd>test<kbd>space</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>

Similarly, when I type:

1.<kbd>space</kbd>test<kbd>space</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>

... the number and period and space engage the automatic numbered list and return makes 2. show up automagically.

I know I can change the text later among bulleted, list and number. The change I wish is to not have the app change my text at all on a document where I type numbers and period and then a space.

Can automatic numbered list / number formatting be turned off in Notes?

Answer (score 8):

The option is Edit - Substitution - Smart Lists. Turn it off and it won't auto-format lists anymore. This option seems only available on macOS though.

Answer (score 1):

The workarounds I've found is I have to change my typing as I don't know a way to disable thus (yet).

Putting a # in front of the number or refraining from typing the period seems to get me what I want in the short term without using another app and typing in notes on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

For iphones/ipads, a helpful tip is to make a keyboard shortcut. In my case, when I type comma dash space I get "- " which formats my lists on the notes app. In settings (for iphone/ipad), go to General > Keyboards then add shortcut of your liking. For example, my phrase would be "- " and shortcut would be ",- ".

Remember: your shortcut might transfer to your macbook keyboard, so use something intuitive.

Hope this helps!